# Epimorphism of sheaves on compact Riemann surface

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, sheaf-theory, riemann-surfaces

In Forster's "Lectures on Riemann Surfaces", section 16 of chapter 2, he describes the following epimorphism of sheaves: suppose $X$ is a compact Riemann surface and $D$ is a divisor of $X$ and take $P \in X$. Consider the sheaves $\mathcal{O}_{D+P}$ and $\mathbb{C}_P$ of vector spaces defined by
$$\mathcal{O}_{D+P}(U) = \{ f \in \mathscr{M}(X) \colon \text{ord}_x(f) \geq -D(x)-P(x),\text{ for each $x \in X$} \},$$
where $P$ denotes the divisor on $X$ which equals 1 on $P$ and 0 elsewhere, and $\mathbb{C}_P(U) = \mathbb{C}$ if $P \in U$ and $\mathbb{C}_P(U) = 0$ if $P \notin U$,
for each open $U \in X$. Then, if $U$ is open in $X$ and $P \notin U$, we define $\beta_U \colon \mathcal{O}_{D+P}(U) \to \mathbb{C}_P(U)$ as the trivial homomorphism, which is clearly surjective. Otherwise, we consider a coordinate neighborhood $(V,z)$ of $P$ such that $z(P)=0$ and, for $f \in \mathcal{O}_{D+P}(U)$, we may consider the Laurent expansion
$$f = \displaystyle\sum_{n=-D(P)-1}^{\infty} c_n z^n.$$
From this, we define $\beta_U(f)$ to be $c_{-D(P)-1}$. Forster then claims that this is surjective, which is the part I don't get.

As far as I understand, it's enough to find a meromorphic function $f \in \mathcal{O}_{D+P}(U)$ with a pole on $P$ of order exactly $-D(P)-1$ and the surjectivity follows by taking $c/c_{-D(P)-1}f$ for any $c \in \mathbb{C}^\times$. But how can we guarantee the existence of such a meromorphic function? This is all defined in order to prove Riemann-Roch, so we "can't" use that or the Riemann Existence Theorem. There's also the problem of controlling the order on other the points, since the function has to be in $\mathcal{O}_{D+P}(U)$. Any suggestions on how to prove this?

Comment: What is $D(P)$? The notation is particularly unfortunate since we have divisors $D$ and $P$.

Comment: You need surjectivity only for small disks $U$ contained in your coordinate chart.

Comment: @TedShifrin $D(P)$ is the value of $D$ at $P$. This is the notation used by Forster, so I'm sticking to it in case someone wants to check it in the source.

Comment: I think I see why it is enough to prove surjectivity only for small disks; epimorphism here is defined to happen when the induced homomorphism on each stalk is surjective. If we take $Q \in X$ distinct from $P$, the stalk $(\mathbb{C}_P)_Q$ is zero; if we take $Q=P$, it is enough to find a small enough disk $U$ around $P$ such that $\mathcal{O}_{D+P}(U) \to \mathbb{C}$ is surjective, which would mean that $(\mathcal{O}_{D+P})_P \to \mathbb{C}$ is surjective. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @TedShifrin Does the following approach work? Since $D$ is a divisor on a compact Riemann Surface, it is different from 0 outside a finite number of points, say, $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\} \in X$. We take a neighborhood $U$ of $P$ which doesn't contain these points $x_i$ and then we consider the coordinate neighborhood $(U \cap V, w=z\vert_{U \cap V})$. We have that $w$ equals zero only on $P$ and it is a zero of order 1, so we can take $(1/w)^{D(P)+1}$, which would be a meromorphic function in $\mathcal{O}_{D+P}(U\cap V)$ with a pole on $P$ of order $-D(P)-1$ and holomorphic elsewhere.

Comment: Well, of course, one of the $x_i$ may be $P$. But yes.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes yes, I meant the $x_i$ distinct from $P$. Thank you very much for guiding me, Ted. I'll write up the answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this, we use the suggestions outlined in the comments. We have an epimorphism of sheaves if the induced morphisms on the stalks are surjective. It is direct that it is surjective for any point $Q \neq P$. Thus, it is enough to find a small enough open set $U \subseteq X$, with $P \in U$, such that $\beta_U$ is surjective, which will imply it is surjective on the stalks at $P$. We proceed as follows: $D$ is a divisor on a compact Riemann surface, so the image of $D$ is different from zero only on a finite number of points, say, $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, one of which may be $P$. That being the case, we choose $U$ of $P$ that doesn't contain any of the $x_i$ distinct from $P$ and then we look at $W=U \cap V$ and $w=z\vert_{U\cap V}$. We have that the only zero of $w$ is at $P$, which is of order 1 since $w$ is a local homeomorphism, so we obtain that $f=(1/w)^{D(P)+1}$ has a pole on $P$ of order exactly $D(P)+1$ and it is holomorphic everywhere else. Thus, $\beta_W(f)=c \neq 0$ and, since it is a homomorphism of vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$, we conclude that $\beta_W$ is surjective by taking any $d \in \mathbb{C}$ and doing
$$\beta_W(\textstyle\frac{d}{c}f) = d.$$